"Publish to Chromatic" github action timeout error
We use the Chromatic action to build and publish or storybook to Chromatic but after a recent push it has started failing with a timeout (after 10 minutes).
The branch has a lot of changes but none seem likely to cause a chromatic build failure (and the stories build fine locally).

After a lot of reverting, I found that the problem was a filename case mismatch.  I'd changed the case of a component file locally but github had the original case.
Renaming the file with git fixed the problem
git mv -f OptionMenuItems.tsx optionMenuItems.tsx

